# How do i install Viro react correctly on windows 10?

Tags: react-native, viro-react

I tried a few options.
Option 1 ([site](https://marmelab.com/blog/2019/04/25/react-native-augmented-reality.html)):

```
npm install -g react-native-cli react-viro-cli
react-viro init test_app
npm start
```

Error!

```js
"." не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
("." is not an internal or external command, executable program or batch file.)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! AR_APP@0.0.1 prestart: `./node_modules/react-viro/bin/run_ngrok.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the AR_APP@0.0.1 prestart script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-03T17_11_44_092Z-debug.log

//package.json
"scripts": {
    "prestart": "./node_modules/react-viro/bin/run_ngrok.sh",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
 },
```

Option 2 ([site](https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/quick-start-windows)):

```js
react-native init test_app --version=0.59.3
cd test_app && npm install -S -E react-viro
npm start
// Running port 8081.
// What's the next step? Ok, i installed ngrok
ngrok http 80
```

I don't know what to do next.
Please give a detailed installation plan to the completed sample on android.

Comment: I got this error when my node version was not up to date. Try updating that (https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm)